# Android gradle, native libs for different architectures

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface, native

I am trying to build **universal** apk for all architectures. Here is my project structure:

```
-App
    -appModule
    -libraryModule
         -libs
             -armeabi
                 -lib.so
         -src
             -java
             -jni
```

Here is my gradle file for libraryModule:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

//    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485309/how-to-build-single-apk-with-andoid-ndk-and-gradle


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "ProxyResolver" // <-- This is the name of AndroidProxy native module
            stl "gnustl_shared"
            cFlags "-std=c++11"
            abiFilters = ['armeabi']
            ldLibs (projectDir.absolutePath + "/libs/armeabi/libresolver.so")
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

As you can see the path for library is **hardcoded**. And right now it **works** on arm-v7 processors. But i need to add support of x86 **without adding a flavor**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess:

```
ndk {

    moduleName "resolver"
    stl "gnustl_shared"
    cFlags "-std=c++11"
    abiFilters = ['armeabi','arm-v7']
}
```

And remove

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried  yuor variant, it doesn't work for me.

libresolver.so is an external library, so i don't think it should be with the same name as module. 

I have module - ProxyResolver that requires so library libresolver.so

Answer (score 0):

Setting `abiFilters` in your `defaultConfig` only adds information to the app's capabilities (only useful for the Installer, i.e. the Installer gives an error when the device you try to install to is not compatible) and does not change which binaries are added to the final `apk`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445685/1827156.

I guess what you want to accomplish is to have different `apk` for different architectures. This is a common usecase, i.e. to reduce build sizes. You can accomplish this by using `splits` in your app's `build.gradle`. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html.

I highly recommend https://www.neotechsoftware.com/blog/native-libraries-part-i-common-pitfalls (I'm not the author).

**Note on working with libraries/`aar`s:**
However, there's one major pitfall when you work with libraries (`aar` instead of `apk`). Imho, you can't (automagically) create different ABI-specific `aar`s. Instead, you create `aar`s containing the binaries for all ABIs. When adding the `aar` to an android app, you specify `splits` in the apps `build.gradle` as mentioned above.