# What is the abiFilters property in a build.gradle file?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I found documentation on what [ABI](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html) is, but I can't find any documentation on what the ndk.abiFilters property does exactly. A couple questions specifically:

1. If I set that property, are the ABIs listed not allowed to run the app? Or is it a filter of the allowed ABIs?
2. What happens if I run the app on a device that doesn't support the filtered ABIs?

Answer (score 12):

1. The ABIs listed are the only one to be supported in the app.
2. The app will not even be installed. The process will fail with this error: *INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS*

These answers are valid only if you have .so libraries inside your apk: If you don't have any .so files packaged in your apk, the ndk.abiFilters will not do anything.